# Open XML SDK - Dynamically create rows

Tags: excel, insert, row, openxml-sdk

I need to use XML SDK to create an Excel file. I have done it before with XML SDK but not sure how to dynamically create rows based on the data.

As such, I have the header and footer which are static. For the body, not sure how to dynamically add rows.

Does anybody have a link to where I can understand this further or some sample code.

I am using this with c# by the way.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You have to keep track of row id's and the update row id's for all the rows after the rows that are inserted dynamically. You'll find yourself writing a library to model and write everything. Instead of reinventing the wheel, if it is possible how about using a third party library that has been developed to eliminate this headache, such as ClosedXML http://closedxml.codeplex.com/ ?